# ggplot is not scaled properly when I want a normal distribution near 0 and y is percent

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

so here is a reproducible example

```
a <- data.frame(rnorm(1000,0,1))
colnames(a) <- c("test")

ggplot(a,aes(test)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..))) +  
    scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
    stat_function(fun='dnorm')
```

This shows my plot at 40% on 0. as I go away from 0 mean and 1 sd the distribution becomes actually closer to the real thing. The values I am using in reality are actually close to `rnorm(1000,0,1)` so it is a very close example

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is? Can you post a picture of your plot? What do you expect to see?

Comment: the histogram has bins, the height of the columns should add up to 1.0; the density function is probability, it's total area should be 1.0; try lower and higher values for `binwidth` in `geom_histogram` and you see the histogram is higher or lower, as each column's height estimates the probability that any chosen number is in that particular bin.

Comment: You also might want to set your seed using `set.seed` so the data from `rnorm` is exactly reproducible.